# golang sync.WaitGroup never finishes

Tags: go

the below code that get worker from channel and execute function "call", all routines finish and print that they are done but wait never finishes,
i traced the counter of WaitGroup by making varible counter incresing when add to wg and decresing when done and it was zero at the end of for loop
any help please

```
package mapreduce

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func schedule(jobName string, mapFiles []string, nReduce int, phase jobPhase, registerChan chan string) {
    var ntasks int
    var n_other int // number of inputs (for reduce) or outputs (for map)
    switch phase {
    case mapPhase:
        ntasks = len(mapFiles)
        n_other = nReduce
    case reducePhase:
        ntasks = nReduce
        n_other = len(mapFiles)

    }

    fmt.Printf("Schedule: %v %v tasks (%d I/Os)\n", ntasks, phase, n_other)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < ntasks; i++ {
        worker := <-registerChan
        doTaskArg := DoTaskArgs{jobName, mapFiles[i], phase, i, n_other}
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            done := call(worker, "Worker.DoTask", doTaskArg, nil)
            if done {
                registerChan <- worker
            } else {
                i = i - 1
            }

        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("Schedule: %v phase done\n", phase)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your code, but I would guess that the channel is blocking go routine. If you put something in a unbuffered channel the goroutine waits until the receiver gets the data from the channel. In your case your routine blocks at `register <- worker` and defer wg.Done() is never called.

Comment: thanks  a lot the problem solved when i add register <- worker in go routine

Comment: @apxp please post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted and the question will be deemed answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The channel is blocking your goroutine. If you put some data into a unbuffered channel the goroutine waits until the receiver gets the the data from the channel. In your case your routine blocks at `register <- worker` and `defer wg.Done()` is never called, because the function is waiting.